# List data in multiple views edit data on click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to figure out what design object to use for my forms application.
I want to make a forms application that looks like below image.

---

[image: My Windows form application]

---

I have so far used splitcontainers for the layout and three gridviews with separate DataSources querying the same table but with different where clause for eatch gridview. This works fine but when i click a row in any of the three gridviews i cant have that data show on the right side becaus i can only get data from one datasource on my labels and textfields etc.
I guess that i should use one datasource but in some way have different where clause to each gridview but i've tried it and i only end up with the same data in all of the gridviews.

If it's to complicated to get together i would instead have a new form window apeare with a click of a button. So if i select one row in any of the gridviews and then click edit a new forms window will open for me to edit data in. How can i do that?

Please advice me how i should try to build the application.
For example; Dont use gridviews use this or that instead. Dont use splitcontainers use this instad. Use bindingsources... etc.

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: As an option you can setup data-binding to edit controls at run-time.

To do so, put edit controls you need on the form and then handle `Enter` event of all `DataGridView` controls and set data binding of your edit controls there. This way, each time you select a grid, the edit controls, show selected row of the active grid.

Comment: Sorry for not commenting back.I realy need to understand more ground ruls before taking on the challange with this, Thanks for giving me a step towards a solution.